# RewriteRule - personal file for each host

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have many projects with the same code on few domains. But some service whants to see personal  key.txt in the root of each domain.

So in my project i create folder "keys" with subfolders with domain names which of them contains own key.txt.

Now it will be good to create RewriteRule in .htaccess for that:

```
/key.txt -> /keys/{http_host}/key.txt
```

How to do it?

Comment: Should be something like this, `RewriteRule ^/key\.txt$ /keys/%{HTTP_HOST}/key.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `RewriteCond` to determine some server variables (see [httpd mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)) and then use the value via backreference `%1` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteRule ^key\.txt /keys/%1/key.txt
```